# PHP Route (for Post method) not working for new version

Tags: php

In Latest laravel version

```
route::post('/Route','classname@method name')
```

route not working and getting this Exception.

```
Target class [PagesController] does not exist.
```

Ex:Route::post('/saveTask', 'TaskController@store');

but This way it worked for get method but not for post

```
Route::get('/about',[FrontendController::class, 'METHODNAME']);
```

Comment: Default namespace as been removed in Laravel 8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing

Comment: Why would it work for `post` when you have specified `get`? If you want to use both HTTP methods then use `Route::any()`

Comment: Please edit the question to specify what framework you're using. We can guess that it's Laravel by looking at the syntax, but we can't be sure. You should also include what version you've swapped between.

Comment: Yes im using Laravel version 9.
Using Route::any() could work for that but i want to know why it did work for get and  not for post

Comment: Because your post route is defined with old syntax. Follow update steps given in the duplicate answer and the upgrade guide, and don't forget to clear route caches.